# How can I get Ruby's RestClient to use a multi-valued query parameter?

Tags: ruby, rest-client

Using the RestClient gem, I need to create a request such as the following:

```
GET http://host/path?p=1&p=2
```

What is the proper syntax to accomplish this?
Note that the receiving host is not Rails.

Tried:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new( 'http://host/path' )
params = { p: '1', p: '2' }  
# ^ Overrides param to have value of 2 (?p=2)

params = { p: ['1','2'] }
# ^ results in 'p[]=abc&p[]=cde' (array [] indicators not wanted)

resource.get( { params: params } )
```

Comment: rest-client 2.0 accepts hash as params. See https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#upgrading-to-rest-client-20-from-1x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* pass the parameters in as a string:

```
resource.get(params: 'p=1&p=2')
```

For instance, using the `restclient` shell:

```
>> RestClient.log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
#<Logger:0x007fa444cbecc0 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007fa444cbec70 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007fa444cbebd0 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x007fa444cbeba8 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x007fa444cbeb58>>>>
>> resource = RestClient::Resource.new( 'http://www.example.net' )
#<RestClient::Resource:0x007fa444c9fdc0 @url="http://www.example.net", @block=nil, @options={}>
>> resource.get(params: 'p=1&p=2')
RestClient.get "http://www.example.net", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Params"=>"p=1&p=2"
# => 200 OK | text/html 1270 bytes
"<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" />\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: \"Open Sans\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 50px;\n        background-color: #fff;\n        border-radius: 1em;\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        body {\n            background-color: #fff;\n        }\n        div {\n            width: auto;\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            border-radius: 0;\n            padding: 1em;\n        }\n    }\n    </style>    \n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>\n    <p><a href=\"http://www.iana.org/domains/example\">More information...</a></p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

If you don't want to write code to build a string, which you should avoid because it's not necessarily straightforward, let Ruby's [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) class cobble it together:

```
require 'uri'
URI::encode_www_form([['p', 1], ['p', 2]])
# => "p=1&p=2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered this issue for RestClient : https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/59
so it seems that it can't be done 'natively' through params.

My solution was to modify the URL, using:

```
query_params = "?p=1&p=2"
resource[query_params].get
```